# How does a given website determine the order of things to be put "in focus" via the tab key?

Tags: html, css

I notice on my favorite sites I can navigate around fairly easily just by tapping around the tab key. Relevant-ish things usually get focus first. Is there a rhyme and reason to the order which focus is given, or is it just the browser scrolling through Divs? Could I define in my own sites the order which focus is given by default via the tab key?

Answer (score 1):

Use the tabindex attribute

So if you have a form with say 4 input fields with tabindex=1, tabindex=2, tabindex=3, tabindex=4. The tabbing will jump between those inputs in that order.

Info here

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Answer (score 0):

tabindex=number determines the ordering of Tab focus.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/a/tabindex

Answer (score -1):

yea you need to make the use of `tabindex` attribute

`tabindex=1`

`tabindex = ordernumber`
`where ordernumber = 1, 2, 3 and so on (unique)`